# WCF return MemoryStream returns blank and status 202

Tags: c#, wcf

My WCF service is proxy-ing another webservice. Whenever I modify the response and return a memory stream, the client gets a 202-Accepted.

```
public Stream MyMethod()
    {
        ...
        ...

        HttpWebResponse httpGetResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpGetRequest.GetResponse();
        var result = httpGetResponse.GetResponseStream();

        //if I return "result" here, I get a 200 and Messagebody contains the contents of the stream
        //return result;

        //modifying content body
        var txtresult = new StreamReader(result, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
        txtresult = txtresult.Replace("old text", "new text");

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtresult), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtresult).Length);
        //same as:- new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtresult));

        stream.Position = 0L;
        //stream.Flush();

        //returns 202 - Accepted. Content body is empty
        return stream;
    }
```

Basically, I just need to modify the contents of the stream before forwading them to the client application. I have verified that the encoding is correct. Beyond that I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. May you please assist

Also, the interface definition is as follows:

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
             BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
             UriTemplate = "teststream")]
    Stream MyMethod();
```

Comment: If anyone can guide me where the 202 comes from, I may be able to debug from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it. Since my service is a proxy, I was passing on the headers I received onto the client without modifying them also. Removing the Content Encoding header before returning the stream worked for me

```
   public Stream MyMethod()
{
    ...

    HttpWebResponse httpGetResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpGetRequest.GetResponse();
    var result = httpGetResponse.GetResponseStream();

    var txtresult = new StreamReader(result, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
    txtresult = txtresult.Replace("old text", "new text");

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtresult), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtresult).Length);

    stream.Position = 0L;
//added this line 
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Remove(HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding);


    //now returns actual content to client
    return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [`OutgoingResponse.ContentType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/service-returns-arbitrary-data-using-the-wcf-web) and add `Content-Disposition` header before returning response as follow:

```
public Stream MyMethod()
{
    ...

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtresult), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtresult).Length);

    stream.Position = 0L;

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=result.txt");

    return stream;
}
```

Comment: ContentType is text/xml in my case. But adding `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=result.txt");` still does the same. I still get a 202 Accepted.
My response looks like this
`HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=2am0nnjmeptellz5v2yoxons; path=/; HttpOnly
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RzpcR2l0XFR1bmRyYVxUdW5kcmFcY2FsZW5kYXJcaG9tZVxmZ2hc?=
Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 13:04:38 GMT
Content-Length: 0`

Comment: Did you try with `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=result.xml");`?

Comment: Yes. It throws an exception `System.InvalidOperationException: 'This collection holds request headers and cannot contain the specified response header.'` on setting the content-type. I suppose it's probably because it's alreadey in the OutgoingResponse headers

Comment: Yes probaby, could you please try `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "inline; filename=result.xml"` then?

Comment: It's still the same. Perhaps if I am able to know where the 202 is set, or what would make a WCF application return a 202, maybe it would be easier finding an alternative way to edit my Stream without causing the error

Comment: By the way do you have `[OperationContract]`attribute  on service?

Comment: Yes. if I return result directly, as shown in code comment ` //if I return "result" here, I get a 200 and Messagebody contains the contents of the stream
        //return result;` the client receives the correct messagebody. The issue happens only is I **modify** the stream and return the edited stream instead